# Hadoop Initialization of all the collectors failed. Error in last collector was :null

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am quite new to hadoop. I am trying to create a simple mapreduce job to find maximum of an entity. However I am getting the error below.

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Initialization of all the collectors failed. Error in last collector was :null
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:414)
```

In another question someone stated that this is because of the values of mapper and reduce however in my case it is not the issue. The definitions of mapper and reducer is below

```
public static class MinimumMapper
    extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{}

public static class MinimumReducer
    extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {}
```

Does anyone have a clue about the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Please import the correct Text class.

If you have imported the below import, you will get that error:

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider.Text;
```

Change it to this.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
```